# Nginx rewrite all html to php

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite all requests like domain.ltd/dev/*.html to domain.ltd/dev/index.php

```
location ~ /dev/\.html {
    rewrite ^ /dev/index.php last;
}
```

this dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/dev/.*\.html {
    rewrite ^ /dev/index.php last;
}
```